# How to preserve the contents of a string that is destroyed later?

Tags: c, string, pointers

I have two strings, `string0` and `string1`. `string0` is of type `char *` while `string1` is of type `const char *`. `string1` points to the data that is allocated on the heap it becomes invalid when the space is freed, but I know that I'll need its contents later.

Since the memory is freed later, I cannot do the following:

```
string0 = (char *) string1;
```

Since both of these are pointers, once the memory is freed, both of them become invalid. That's why I tried this:

```
strcpy(string0, string1);
```

But that produces an error: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. What else can I try to preserve the contents of `string1` even after freeing the heap?

Comment: Allocate memory and copy `string1 to string0`, you can either use `strlen + 1` and `malloc` to size and allocate the new block and then `strcpy (string0, string1);`, or if you have it, just use `string0 = strdup (string1);` to both allocate and copy at once. Then return a pointer to `string0` that will survive return as it has *allocated-storage-duration*. Your second option is to declare `string1` as `static` so it has *static-storage-duration*.

Comment: Add your complete `source code`

Comment: @Binary_10 But it's almost 1200 lines.

Comment: If that data is needed later, why is it being freed?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons I have no idea. `string1` is returned by the API function, and API itself frees it later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`strcpy` does not allocate memory for you. You need to allocate enough memory to `string0` before copying anything into it. Don't forget 1 more for the terminating null byte.

```
// No size is needed because `char` is always 1 byte
char *string0 = malloc( strlen(string1) + 1 );
strcpy( string0, string1 );
```

The [POSIX `strdup` function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strdup.html) does this for you. It is safer and easier to understand.

```
char *string0 = strdup(string1);
```

Or, if possible, just don't free `string1` in the first place.

Comment: I guess great minds think alike... Yes, the "`string1` points to the data that is allocated on the heap..." is a bit of a head-scratcher.